# MongoDB aggregation result as a nested Json

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-java-driver

This is a piece of my MongoDB collection :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b0ba203a20b54e3b1e09e4"), "i" : 0, "x" : 1, "id" : 2, "info" : { "j" : 0 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b0ba203a20b54e3b1e09e5"), "i" : 1, "x" : 2, "id" : 2, "info" : { "j" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b0ba203a20b54e3b1e09e6"), "i" : 2, "x" : 3, "id" : 2, "info" : { "j" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b0ba203a20b54e3b1e09e7"), "i" : 3, "x" : 4, "id" : 2, "info" : { "j" : 3 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b0ba203a20b54e3b1e09e8"), "i" : 4, "x" : 5, "id" : 2, "info" : { "j" : 4 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b0ba203a20b54e3b1e09e9"), "i" : 5, "x" : 6, "id" : 2, "info" : { "j" : 5 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b0ba203a20b54e3b1e09ea"), "i" : 6, "x" : 7, "id" : 2, "info" : { "j" : 6 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b0ba203a20b54e3b1e09eb"), "i" : 7, "x" : 8, "id" : 2, "info" : { "j" : 7 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b0ba203a20b54e3b1e09ec"), "i" : 8, "x" : 9, "id" : 2, "info" : { "j" : 8 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b0ba203a20b54e3b1e09ed"), "i" : 9, "x" : 10, "id" : 2, "info" : { "j" : 9 } }
```

.
.
and, it goes.

What I need to do is for each unique "id", get the sum of all "i"'s, "x"'s and "info.j"'s. I am perfectly able to do it with :

```
AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$id")
                .append("i", new Document("$sum", "$i"))
                .append("x", new Document("$sum", "$x"))
                .append("j", new Document("$sum", "$info.j")))));
```

with the output as :

```
{ "_id" : 3, "i" : 49995000, "x" : 50005000, "id" : 3, "j" : 49995000 }
{ "_id" : 1, "i" : 99990000, "x" : 100010000, "id" : 1, "j" : 99990000 }
{ "_id" : 2, "i" : 49995000, "x" : 50005000, "id" : 2, "j" : 49995000 }
```

So far, everything looks perfect. Except for, I cant get to keep the "j" in the output as a nested object inside "info" like in the original collection. What can I do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregation frameork requires that all field names used in accumulators be a single name, as the next argument is presumed to be an accumulator itself in the structre. Nor can you use "dot notation" as this is also invalid.

The only thing to do is to [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/):

```
AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$id")
                .append("i", new Document("$sum", "$i"))
                .append("x", new Document("$sum", "$x"))
                .append("j", new Document("$sum", "$info.j"))
        ),
        new Document("$project",new Document("i",1)
                .append("x", new Document("x",1)),
                .append("x", new Document("info",
                   new Document("j", "$j")
                ))
        )
));
```

Or of course just simply process each result and alter the BSON structure there in much the same way.

Comment: This works! Will look into $project accumulator more.

Answer (score 2):

Please Try the below :

```
AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = collection.aggregate(
Arrays.asList(
    new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$id")
            .append("i", new Document("$sum", "$i"))
            .append("x", new Document("$sum", "$x"))
            .append("j", new Document("$sum", "$info.j"))),
    new Document("$project",new Document("_id","$_id").
           .append("i","$i")
           .append("x",  "$x")
           .append("info", new Document("j", "$j")))
    ));
```